# Is there a way to pass a compound term as a parameter from a form in swi-prolog

Tags: forms, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm using swi-prolog 7.3.31.

I have a compound term `question` of the form:

```
question(q_(Question),y_(Yes),n_(No))
```

where `Yes` and `No` can be either an `atom` or an other compound term `question` and so on.

I'm using using a form with `reply_html_page` where I display the text of the question `Question` and where I have two submit buttons one for 'yes' and one for 'no'.

Here is a sample of my form for the 'yes' button:

```
form([class = 'form-inline ',
      action = '/choice_handler',
      method = 'POST'], [
      input([name = choice,
             id = choice,
             type = hidden,
             class = 'form-control',
             value = 'yes']),
      input([name = question,
             type = hidden,
             value = Yes ]),
      button([class = 'btn btn-default yes',
              type = submit], ['yes']) ])
```

Here is my issue, I want to pass the value of `Yes` in order to recursively display a new question or the final result, however I fail to do so because the `value` of the input form must be an atom and not a coupound term.

Hence the question: is there any way to pass the compound term to the `handler`?

Comment: @Boris, thanks for your answer, however I'm still lost in the dark. I can't find my way with `\Term`. I have try to convert my `compound` to a string and then revert back, however I can't get the same compound.

Comment: I actually completely misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that an atom is often **enough** when exchanging data, because you can use **`atom_to_term/3`** to convert an atom to a compound term:

### [`atom_to_term(+Atom, -Term, -Bindings)`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_to_term/3)

> Use Atom as input to `read_term/2` using the option variable_names and  return the read term in Term and the variable bindings in Bindings. Bindings is a list of `Name = Var` couples, thus providing access to the actual variable names. See also `read_term/2`. If Atom has no valid syntax, a syntax_error exception is raised. New code should use read_term_from_atom/3.

**Example**:

```
?- atom_to_term('the(f(X,Y),Z)', Term, Bindings).
Term = the(f(_1596, _1598), _1604),
Bindings = ['X'=_1596, 'Y'=_1598, 'Z'=_1604].
```

Thus, you can simply take the atom and recover the compound term, under suitably general assumptions.

Comment: thanks for this reply.  'atom_to_term' does what I ask for. However, after a lot of testing, in my case it doesn't solve my problem. I may still have something wrong somewhere but I don't know what!